# How can i convert a dictionary into a list of lists of key-value pairs?

Tags: python

I would like to convert a python dictionary into a list of lists with each sub-list containing two items, the key and the value.
I made this:

```
my_dict = {'key1': 1, 'key2': 2, 'key3': 'value'}
dict_keys = my_dict.keys()
key_value = []
for key in dict_keys:
    t = []
    t.append(key)
    t.append(my_dict[key])
    key_value.append(t)
print(key_value) # [['key1', 1], ['key2', 2], ['key3', 'value']]
```

It works, but is long. Is there a better method?

Answer (score 0):

`[[k, v] for k, v in my_dict.items()]` should do the job

Comment: Kindly check the your answer , it is not running. Throw exception

Comment: @JohnByro fixed, just replaced {} with [], in order to make the result a list instead of set.